# using a function from .so library without a header file, knowing the function signature

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc

I would like to apologize for terminology and possible stupid questions, I'm a total newbie in C++ and OS architecture.

I have a library.so file compiled for x86 32bit that I need to use a function from. With the help of IDA, I know the symbols and the name of the function and its parameters.

I created a .cpp file with `dlopen()` call to import the library and then getting the pointer to the function by its name and, finally, calling the function from the lib with two parameters: `"4d"`,`"13a7330873d6e062"`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    void *handle;
    char * (*cipher)(const char *,const char *);
    char *error;
    handle = dlopen ("/path/to/library.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    if (!handle) {
        fprintf (stderr, "%s\n", dlerror());
        exit(1);
    }
    dlerror();    /* Clear any existing error */
    cipher = (char * (*)(const char *,const char *)) dlsym(handle, "known_function_name");
    if ((error = dlerror()) != NULL)  {
        fprintf (stderr, "%s\n", error);
        exit(1);
    }
    printf ("%s\n", (*cipher)("4d","13a7330873d6e062"));
    dlclose(handle);
    return 0;
}
```

Then I tried to compile it with g++-4.6 (because as I see in the contents of the lib it was compiled using gcc 4.6) with the following options:

```
g++-4.6 -o test test.cpp -ldl
```

It compiles without any warnings/errors, but when I launch ./test, I'm getting:

```
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so: invalid ELF header
```

If I try to do readelf -h /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so, I'm getting something like "Unable to read in 0x2074 bytes of section headers ... Not an ELF file". OK, if I do a symlink to /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 , then it reads fine, but when I launch the file again:

```
/path/to/library.so: undefined symbol: __stack_chk_guard
```

I'm getting exactly the same messages if I try to import the .so file into a Java test class code.

**The question is**: how do I properly import the .so lib into my proram knowing the signature of a function. I don't have a header file for the library.

Thanks

**UPDATE**: I tried to put

```
void *__stack_chk_guard;
```

into my test.cpp file (if I understood that right) and recompiled it with `-fstack-protector` option, but it did not help, I'm still getting

```
/path/to/library.so: undefined symbol: __stack_chk_guard
```

Also: it compiles fine against my current /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so , BUT when I launch it then, it complaints about it as I stated earlier:

```
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so: invalid ELF header
```

If I back it up and make a symlink /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so -> /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 , then it won't compile with:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0xc): undefined reference to `__libc_csu_fini'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x11): undefined reference to `__libc_csu_init'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

but then it runs with

```
/path/to/library.so: undefined symbol: __stack_chk_guard
```

Comment: Your version of 'glibc' was compilled without 'glibc stack guard support' but 'library.so' with it. That's why '__stack_chk_guard' is undefined.

Comment: hmm, can I somehow install the glibc from package repo with stack guard? Or do I need to recompile only manually? I'm on Ubuntu saucy

Comment: Ubuntu 13.10 should have that feature out of the box. Right way is to recompile 'library.so' for ubuntu. Workaround - just place that line somewhere into source: 'void *__stack_chk_guard;' (or 'uintptr_t stack_chk_guard') and initialized it with random value.

Comment: Error could go away if you compile test.cpp with option `-fstack-protector`. Important point is that you must compile each source with `-fstack-protector` or with `-fno-stack-protector`.

Comment: @alexander thanks a lot for your comments, see above, I updated my question. In fact, I have two libc.so , with the first ones it compiles with no errors, but does not want to launch, with the second one it can't compile (see the error in the updated section), but at least tried to run and complaints about stack guard

Comment: Try that line as workaround: `void *_stack_chk_guard;` (with one underscore  prefix). C compiler automatically prepend each symbol with '_'.

Comment: If you linking against 32bit library than you must build 32bit application. If want to build 32bit application on 64bit Ubuntu, than you must pass '-m32' to gcc and install ia32-libs-dev (see that [answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/12957)).

Comment: still the same: /path/to/library.so: undefined symbol: __stack_chk_guard . Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but I added this line `void *_stack_chk_guard;` before the declaration of handle pointer in test.cpp, and then recompiled. Also, I'm on 32bit machine, uname -m reports i686

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54726/discussion-between-alexander-and-alexey).

Answer (score 0):

Verify, that library.so has all dependences loaded correctly. If you are using different libraries there is probably no __stack_chk_guard in it. Check with ldd and other tools.

btw __stack_chk_guard is not very popular on x86 architecture...